# What does |& (vertical bar, ampersand) mean in bash?

Tags: bash

What does `|&` (vertical bar, ampersand) mean in bash? E.g.

```
node app.js |& logger -t my-app &
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`|&` is syntactic sugar for `2>&1 |` added in Bash 4.
I.e. it redirects both standard and error outputs of command preceding `|&` to standard input of the following command.

[Advanced bash scripting guide](http://www.tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/abs-guide.html#IO-REDIRECTION) documentation

Comment: Also documented in the manual: https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Pipelines